# Incompatible generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I'm unable to see why I cannot use a particular generic type in the definition of another.

So I have this:

```
public abstract class MdiWorkspaceController<TWorkItemController, TMdiWorkspaceView, TWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView> 
    : ViewableWorkspaceController<TWorkItemController>
    where TMdiWorkspaceView : class, IMdiWorkspaceView<TWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView, TWorkItemMainView>
    where TWorkItemViewFrame : class, IWorkItemViewFrame<TWorkItemMainView>
    where TWorkItemMainView : class, IWorkItemMainView
    where TWorkItemController : ViewableWorkItemController{}
```

and Im trying to use a

```
  public partial class TabbedWorkspaceView<TWorkItemMainView>
        : KryptonNavigator,
        IMdiWorkspaceView<TabbedWorkItemViewFrame<TWorkItemMainView>, TWorkItemMainView, TWorkItemMainView>
        where TWorkItemMainView : AbstractWorkItemView
```

as the TTabbedWorkspaceView in a more concrete implementation TabbedWorkspaceController as below:

```
public class TabbedWorkspaceController<TWorkItemController, TTabbedWorkspaceView, TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView>
    : MdiWorkspaceController<TWorkItemController, TTabbedWorkspaceView, TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView>
    where TWorkItemController : ViewableWorkItemController
    where TTabbedWorkspaceView : TabbedWorkspaceView<TWorkItemMainView>
    where TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame : TabbedWorkItemViewFrame<TWorkItemMainView>
    where TWorkItemMainView : AbstractWorkItemView
```

but Im getting an error saying that TTabbedWorkspaceView must be convertible to

```
IMdiWorkspaceView<TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame<TWorkItemMainView>, TWorkItemMainView, TWorkItemMainView>
```

in order to use it as parameter TMdiWorkspaceView in the generic class

```
 MdiWorkspaceController<TWorkItemController, TTabbedWorkspaceView, TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView>
```

Now I'll happily admit that I'm at my personal boundary of "clever" code but after this everything becomes completely concrete and simplified at the application level so I'd like to continue to use the design I have.

**Update:**

Ok so thanks to everyones help I have resolved this issue, I needed to let the generic type flow through to TabbedWorkspaceView, instead I had declared it. So new versions are:

```
 public partial class TabbedWorkspaceView<TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView>
        : KryptonNavigator,
        IMdiWorkspaceView<TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView, TWorkItemMainView>
        where TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame : TabbedWorkItemViewFrame<TWorkItemMainView>
        where TWorkItemMainView : AbstractWorkItemView
```

and then:

```
 public class TabbedWorkspaceController<TWorkItemController, TTabbedWorkspaceView, TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView>
        : MdiWorkspaceController<TWorkItemController, TTabbedWorkspaceView, TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView>
        where TWorkItemController : ViewableWorkItemController
        where TTabbedWorkspaceView : TabbedWorkspaceView<TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame, TWorkItemMainView>
        where TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame : TabbedWorkItemViewFrame<TWorkItemMainView>
        where TWorkItemMainView : AbstractWorkItemView
```

Then at the application level I can just:

```
public class TappWorkspaceController
    : TabbedWorkspaceController<TappWorkItemController, TappWorkspaceView, TappWorkItemViewFrame, TappWorkItemView>
```

Comment: “I'm at my personal boundary of "clever" code” Which is exactly why you should avoid code like this if possible.

Comment: This code hurts to read. Also what is a KryptonNavigator? It sounds cool!

Comment: @Quibblesome KryptonNavigator is the tab control component of Component Factories Krypton Control Suite. This is a somewhat painful layer in that Im bringing together the underlying abstractions from other layers of the UI workflow and making them use concrete implementations of Krypton Suite like KryptonNavigator.   For this pain I get an underlying ui and workflow abstraction plus a decoupled  application layer that I can swap in/out different UI components, say WinForms, Wpf, telerik, etc. So its nasty but thin.

Comment: @svick - Yep its a fair point and I can readily simplify it by swapping in the underlying interfaces and then using "as" throughout this layer but it would be nice to avoid all that boxing. Its nasty but there's no real logic in this layer, it's just a merge layer for choosing and decoupling a set UI components/controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post is relevant:

[Constraints are not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx)

Your question hurts my brain, but I believe this is what's happening:

- The compiler does not "know" that `TTabbedWorkspaceView` is a `TabbedWorkspaceView`, because this information is only given through a constraint which is not part of the signature.
- `TTabbedWorkspaceView` is passed to `MdiWorkspaceController` as `TMdiWorkspaceView`, through `TabbedWorkspaceController`'s inheritance.
- `MdiWorkspaceController`'s constraint validation fails for `TMdiWorkspaceView`, because it was given as something that is not "known" to be an `IMdiWorkspaceView`.

The solution: [CA1005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182129.aspx).

Comment: Constraints are not part of the signature, but this is not about overload resolution, which is where that applies.

Comment: @svick You have erroneously made the leap in logic that since type signatures apply to overload resolution that they must *only* apply to overload resolution. That is not true. Please verify your assumptions before downvoting based on them.

Comment: You mean like verifying my assumptions by making the code compile  with a tiny change in `IMdiWorkspaceView`? (I was going to write “fix” instead of “compile”, but actually fixing the code to make it reasonable would require much more.)

Comment: @svick Your assumption was that the linked post is not relevant because it only applies to overload resolution. This is incorrect. For instance, the same principle is in effect when you try to create two generic classes with the same name and same number of type parameters that differ by constraints.

Comment: Thanks, Im going to stick my guns, even though the solution is "CA1005". This workspace controller is the outer most container class of the whole UI structure implementation so Im prepared for it all to come to a head in these literally 3 classes of the whole assembly. Tracing back through the rest of what you have said now.

Comment: @nmclean You're right it was a "constraints are not part of the signature" problem and I had defined the TTabbedWorkItemViewFrame which hand goes in hand with the workspaceview, one class too "high".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic type in the definition of another. This is a simplified example:

```
class Program
{  
    public interface IBadFoo
    {
        void DoSomethingUnusual();
    }

    public interface IFoo
    { 
        void DoSomething();
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {           
        }
    }

    public abstract class SomeGenericBase<IFooClass>
        where IFooClass : IFoo
        //where IFooClass : IBadFoo
    {
        public abstract void DoSomethingElse();
    }

    public class SomeGeneric<FooClass> : SomeGenericBase<FooClass>
        where FooClass : Foo, new()
    {
        public override void DoSomethingElse()
       {
           FooClass fc = new FooClass();
           fc.DoSomething();
       }
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
       SomeGeneric<Foo> someGen = new SomeGeneric<Foo>();
       someGen.DoSomethingElse();
   }
}
```

Note that if I comment `where IFooClass : IFoo` and uncomment `//where IFooClass : IBadFoo` then I get a similar error because there is no conversion from Foo to IBadFoo. So, I think that somewhere in your inheritance structure and parameters there is no path or a path mismatch for the compiler. I suggest that you remove parameters and simplify the problem space until you find the source.

Answer (score 1):

This code is really complicated and it took me a while to untangle it (and I still don't understand what is it supposed to mean).

I *think* that the problem is that `MdiWorkspaceController` requires that its `TMdiWorkspaceView` and `TWorkItemViewFrame` were directly related, but you don't guarantee that.

To fix that, you can change the `IMdiWorkspaceView` interface from something like:

```
public interface IMdiWorkspaceView<TWorkItemViewFrame, T2, T3>
```

to:

```
public interface IMdiWorkspaceView<in TWorkItemViewFrame, T2, T3>
```

The `in` basically loosens the requirements on `TWorkItemViewFrame`, which will make your code compile.

If the definition of `IMdiWorkspaceView` is such that it won't compile with the `in`, it means your code as written wouldn't be type-safe.

Comment: Ok I actually have public interface IMdiWorkspaceView<out TWorkItemViewFrame, out TWorkItemMainView, in TAttachableWorkItemMainView> for the interface. I wanted the  TWorkItemViewFrame to be covariant so it could use either the defined base type or a derived type of base.